# How to open a Kendo modal when a Kendo button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have a Kendo button as below:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                            .Name("select_button")
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button" })
                            .Content("Choose")
                            .Events(ev => ev.Click("onClick")))
```

Then I have a modal as below:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="select-add">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                  This is the modal
            </div>
</div>
```

And I am calling my modal on click event of the button as below:

```
                <script>
                    $('.select_button').click(function (event) {
                        $('#select-add').modal("show");
                    })
                </script>
```

When I run the application and click the button. nothing happens.

I am very new to Kendo UI. Can you please help me understand what am I doing wrong and what is needed? I want to open the modal when the Kendo button is clicked.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!